# Building Cross Compiler on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, gcc, cross-compiling

I'm trying to build GCC to target the Motorola 68000 processor on my Mac. I'm running OS 10.11.1.  I'm able to build and run m68k-elf-gcc but, it always falls back on LLVM giving me a Clang error.

I've read that I may need to install Homebrew and, install gcc via that. I've done that, built m68k-elf-gcc via Homebrew's gcc and, it still doesn't work.

```
../configure --prefix=/Users/Shared/GCC --target=m68k-elf \
  --enable-languages=c,c++ --with-isl=/Users/Shared/GCC \
  --with-gmp=/Users/Shared/GCC --with-mpfr=/Users/Shared/GCC \
  --with-mpc=/Users/Shared/GCC --enable-static --disable-shared \
  --disable-libgcc --disable-libstdc++-v3 --disable-libquadmath \
  --disable-libssp
```

Comment: What is "a clang error" and "it doesn't work"?  Be specific.

Comment: Clang is the front end of the LLVM compiler. It's the compiler that comes with Xcode. It produces an error because it's not designed to compile into m68k opcode. "still doesn't work" means that the previous problem persists.

Comment: What John is trying to say is "show your errors".  And I'd do so for both the clang build and the Homebrew/gcc version.  You may have something else wrong other than the configure line.

Comment: I don't see how the error is relevant. I'm not trying to use Clang. I'm trying to use my cross compiler. Clang will report an error like this: `clang: error: unsupported option '--isa=m68ka'`. The error makes sense if you read the problem I'm having but, the error is irrelevant. My question isn't about Clang it's about the cross compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After building on Linux I could see that m68k-elf-gcc was also looking for GNU Assembler. After I built binutils the compiler works perfectly on OS X and Linux.

I'm assuming when I tried executing m68k-elf-gcc on OS X that gcc failed to find as and defaulted to whatever is my environment variables i.e. Clang.